# Rerun Failed test Cases in Cucumber Automatically using Maven Command

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, cucumber, gherkin

I am not using TestNG. I wanna rerun failed test scenarios using Maven automatically.

When I trigger mvn should run test and create rerun.txt for all the failed scenarios. I am able to create rerun.txt on runtime but can't run failed scenarios automatically.

**testrunner.java**

```
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/main/features/",
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-report", "json:target/cucumber- 
    report/report.json", "rerun:target/rerun/rerun.txt"},
    tags = {"@test"},
```

**pom.xml**

```
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
           <includes>
                 <include>**/*testrunner*.java</include>
           </includes>
         </configuration>
       </plugin>
```

Also, I am aware that I can create another test runner for a rerun and run it manually. When I do that and add it on pom.xml. testReRunner sometime runs without failed test cases create in rerun.txt file.

Comment: JUnit and TestNG are built for this... why wouldn't you use them? Not to mention for asserts inside of your tests.

Comment: @JeffC There are too many test cases to add any logic in the script. It has to go through the framework level. Also, We are not using TestNG.

Comment: Did you try to add `<rerunFailingTestsCount>1</rerunFailingTestsCount>` to `<configuration>` of surefire plugin? It works with JUnit so there is a chance it will work with Cucumber

Comment: @Fenio Thanks for the help. I was able to rerun failed test cases using your method. I have one more question. How does this affect reporting ?

Comment: @AjayGC As far as I remember, you'll have both results in test report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maven-surefire-plugin` has built-in option to rerun failed tests.

Simply add `<rerunFailingTestsCount>1</rerunFailingTestsCount>` in `<configuration>` of surefire plugin